# Display full branch name in Gitlab Pipeline page

Tags: gitlab

[image]

How do I get Gitlab to display the full branch name in the CI/CD > Pipelines page?

Currently, I have to hover over each commit to get the full branch name of the commit.

Comment: I ended up using the gitlab api to get the pipeline info (I use the httpie and jq command line tools) https -b <your gitlab url>/api/v4/projects/<project id>/pipelines "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN" | jq -r '.[] | ((.id|tostring) + " - " + .ref + " - " + .created_at + " - " + .status)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, but you can open an issue if you want

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
job_name:
  script:
    - export $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#list-all-environment-variables

Comment: hi etusm, I want to display the full branch name in the UI of the gitlab pipelines page rather than obtain the branch name in the runner